# JQuery DataTable fnUpdate not updating values from object source: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'fnSetData' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
       "aoColumns": [
        {"mData": "name"}
       ]
     });
     // Sample model
     var Person = function() {
       this.name = null;
     };
     p = new Person(); 

     // Add first row.
     oTable.fnAddData(p); 

     // Try first update.
     oTable.fnUpdate( {name: 'hardcoded'}, 0 ); // <--- Works

     // Change the name property.
     p.name = 'updated';
     oTable.fnUpdate( p, 0 ); // <--- Doesn't work
   } );
```

I can't get this to work, when i run the oTable.fnUpdate( p, 0 ); i am getting

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'fnSetData' of undefined

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a proper object to initialize persons. Then you can use later fnUpdate with an object call like you did

```
 var p = {
     name: null
 };
```

See here for full code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T45p9/)

Comment: uhm what's the difference between two methods, aren't both valid object initializers?

Comment: @brazorf Well you have a function there, and not an object. Your hardcoded stuff works cos its targets an object ( name ) of aoColumns. Practically you passed a function to fnUpdate and not an object. And since fnUpdate only works with object/array/string, it throws your typeError

Comment: Always thought there was some implicit object casting with that! Thank you anyway.